# Jquery toggle on off

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have simple question but i can not find this anywhere. 
I have toggle button from jquery UI.:

```
$(function() {
  $( "#check" ).button();
});

var isChecked = $('#check').prop('checked');
```

I want to have that work like a switch on/off. Show alert("checked") when checked and alert("not checked") when not checked. Appriceate your help.

Comment: Check this out: http://jqueryui.com/button/#checkbox

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
   $('#check').click(function(){
            if($(this).prop("checked") == true){
                alert("checked.");
            }
            else if($(this).prop("checked") == false){
                alert("not checked.");
            }
        });
```

Comment: This code doesn't account for the possibility that the checkbox is toggled using the keyboard.

Comment: @TimBurch I'd like to quote the sites guidelines. "When should I vote down?

Use your downvotes whenever you encounter an egregiously sloppy, no-effort-expended post, or an answer that is clearly and perhaps dangerously incorrect." This answer shouldn't be down voted because he missed one possible scenario of toggling.

Comment: @Dan According to the site guidelines you quoted, I should have voted down the answer, because it's "clearly...incorrect," insofar as it is incomplete and, if accepted as it has been and implemented, could lead to confusion and time wasted on the part of the OP, his or her clients, and users.

Comment: @TimBurch This answer is not incorrect it's just possible incomplete. The OP never said they needed the ability for the user to use the keyboard and IMHO with the visual effects of a toggle I can't imagine a user doing anything but clicking it. That said you're allowed to have your own opinion but in mine this isn't "dangerously incorrect" it just doesn't cover all possible scenarios.

Answer (score 2):

You can add `change` event listener to the button.

```
$('#check').change(function(event){
    var msg = 'checked';
    if(!this.checked) 
       msg = 'not ' + msg;
    alert(msg);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The following code should do it:

```
$('#check').bind('click keyup', function(){
    alert(($(this).is(':checked')) ? 'checked' : 'not checked');
});
```